# UIView not moving when changing its center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView, I am changing its center but the UIView isn't moving.

pLocation is a UIView* created in a NIB file.  I am trying to move it changing its center (or frame or anything really).  Here is my current test case.

```
- (void)Update {

    [mWorldObj Update];

    static float xVal = 10;
    xVal += 0.1;

    NSLog(@"Before Loc X: %f Y: %f", pLocation.center.x, pLocation.center.y);

    pLocation.center = CGPointMake(xVal, 100.0);
    [pLocation setNeedsDisplay];   //Test
    [pLocation setNeedsLayout];    //Test
    pLocation.hidden = !pLocation.hidden;  //Test - Hide and unhide to force re-draw

    NSLog(@"After Loc X: %f Y: %f - Frame %f %f", pLocation.center.x, pLocation.center.y, pLocation.frame.origin.x, pLocation.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Before and after print out the correct numbers

```
] Before Loc X: 60.500000 Y: 55.000000
] After Loc X: 10.100000 Y: 100.000000 - Frame -50.400002 45.000000
] Before Loc X: 10.100000 Y: 100.000000
] After Loc X: 10.200001 Y: 100.000000 - Frame -50.299999 45.000000
] Before Loc X: 10.200001 Y: 100.000000
] After Loc X: 10.300001 Y: 100.000000 - Frame -50.199997 45.000000
```

but the view never moves onscreen.  How do I force a re-draw of the view?

Edit:

I have animations that play before hand and mess with other buttons.  When I add moving the location to that animation like so:

```
-(void)  EnableButtons {
    pInfo.hidden = false;
    pMore.hidden = false;
    //SetLocButtonsClickable(true);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowButtons" context:nil];    
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];   
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    // Make the animatable changes.
    pInfo.alpha = 1.0;
    pMore.alpha = 1.0;
    pLocation.center = CGPointMake(200, 000);   //****Added test code

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The Location moves just fine

Comment: Try moving it by more then 0.1, try 2.0 instead. AFAIK the values are pixles, and there are no 0.1 pixles...

Comment: An increment of 0.1 is a bit small, have you tried larger values, e.g. 5 ? Also, setting the center already redraws the view (without calling `drawRect:`) so the following three lines are unnecessary (and setNeedsLayout only has an effect on its subviews).

Comment: and if you just hide it (pLocation.hidden = YES), does it hide? Is the view properly connected to the outlet?

Comment: @Zaky German: Actually the values are not pixels, but in a completely canonical view tree it does match to a pixel (on non-retina devices; on a retina device one point actually spans four pixels). Setting a non-identity `transform` on a view or on one of its parents destroys that point-to-pixel relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations can only be performed off the main thread.  Ensure animation code is being called from the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, dunno how your view hierarchy is set up, but I've recently had a very similar problem and it was caused because the containing UIView had resized to a size smaller than the view I was moving, so in practice It couldn't move because it was held in place by it's containing view.

So, if your pLocation is contained in another UIView, it might be worth checking its frame too to verify it allows for pLocation's movement.

Comment: I'll look and see how large the parent view is but I don't think that is it.  I can move it with animations... see edit above.